# How to specify a list of constraints for scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this from the optimize manual
(using the minimization routine SLSQP). My problem has an array of variables x0 and from that I'm trying to construct a list of constraints for my function.

```
L = 2
N = 2

x0 = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=(L*L*N*2,))
x0 = x0.reshape(L,L,N,2)
ff = x0[:, :, :, 0] + 1j*x0[:, :, :, 1]
```

The constraints need to be of the form: ff[x,y,1]**2 + ff[x,y,2]**2 + ... + ff[x,y,N]**2 = 1

I think this should be doable but I'm learning Python as I go with this problem. I hope it's not a trivial place to have gotten stuck. My attempt so far,

```
for i_x in range(L):
for i_y in range(L):
    cons = {'type':'eq', 'fun': np.sum(np.abs(ff[i_x, i_y, :])**2) - 1}

x0 = x0.reshape(L*L*N*2, )
scipy.optimize.minimize(func, x0, constraints=cons)
```

And now,

```
def constraints(x0, L, N, cons):
x0 = x0.reshape(L, L, N, 2)

for i_x in range(L):
    for i_y in range(L):
            def con(x0, i_x = i_x, i_y = i_y):
                return np.sum(np.abs((x0[i_x, i_y, :, 0] + 1j*x0[i_x, i_y, :, 1])**2)) - 1
            cons.append({'type':'eq', 'fun': con})

return cons
```

But I receive the error, "too many indices for the array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a problem with your code is that it overwrites the constraint `cons`. As a result, the only constraint that the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function sees is `np.sum(np.abs(ff[-1, -1, :])**2) = 1` where `-1` means the last element L-1. I suggest initializing an empty list, then appending to it:

```
    cons = []
    for i_x in range(L):
        for i_y in range(L):
            cons.append({'type':'eq', 'fun': ...)
```

The second problem is that  the constraint must be parametrized by the same vector as the function you are trying to minimize, i.e. it must be a function of a vector with shape (L * L * N * 2, ). Yours instead is a function of `ff`, which has shape (L,L,N,) and is a constant ("frozen" at creation time with the initial value `x0`) that does not depend on the current iteration of the minimization algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've updated my attempt. I think the problem now is that the minimizer needs the variables in a single list and I have defined my constraints using an array. Working on a solution but I don't have any immediate ideas.

Comment: Because the argument to your constraint function is a 1D vector, you need to reshape it before you can use many indices, as you are trying to, e.g.: `x0.reshape(L,L,N,2)[i_x, i_y, :, 0]`